# SMTP Gmail Sends Email on Localhost but not once website is running

Tags: c#, smtp, gmail

I have a website that has a 'contact me' form. It works on localhost but once the website is up and running it won't work any longer.

I know Gmail only allows you to authenticate using SMTP/IMAP/POP3 after you've authenticated via the web from a particular device. How do I do that? And if anything that is a Gmail alternative I can use that won't run into this problem.

```
                client.Connect("smtp.gmail.com", 587, false);
                client.Authenticate("example@gmail.com", "123456789");
                client.Send(message);
                client.Disconnect(true);
```

Comment: Are you running website as a service?   What credentials is the service?  The from address and the credentials of the email must match.  So when you are running local you are using your default credentials.  When running as a website the credentials are different.

Comment: @jdweng I am using Azure app services, in that account, my email used for the account is the same one I am authenticating from the code.

Comment: The problem is the credentials.  The smtp is being made with the credentials of the service.  The service has to be run with the same credentials as the FROM address which is the credentials the email account.

Answer (score 0):

Check your gmail inbox for messages of blocked sign-in attempts, you're website may be hosted in a different country on a different ip address then the oe gmail is used to etc. so you'd have to allow that sign in.